# run selected link in background, update url and icon of link?

Tags: php, jquery, url, icons, toggle

I'm not quite sure how to word this.. but here goes :)

I have links similar to :

```
<a href='#' class='tip' id='4a' onclick=\"load('go.php?go=4a');\"><img src='go.png'></a>
<a href='#' class='tip' id='6a' onclick=\"load('go.php?go=6a');\"><img src='go.png'></a>
<a href='#' class='tip' id='8a' onclick=\"load('go.php?go=8a');\"><img src='go.png'></a>
```

When someone clicks on the first link I want to run `go.php?go=4a` in the background, and change the icon on the link to `stop.png`, but also change the URL of this link to `go.php?stop=4a`.

If they think click the same link, I'd want to revert all this back to what it was.
Effectively making each link a go / stop toggle !

I seem to think jquery can do this, but I can't find any examples.

Anyone any ideas ?

Thanks :)

Comment: this is exactly what AJAX is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have jQuery loaded, and you have a container `x` which serves as your page content, you can use `$.ajax` to load dynamic content to the container and have it load/stop like:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.tip').on(' click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            container = $('#x'),
            prevHTML = container.html(),
            req = {};
        if ($this.hasClass('go')) {
            req.abort();
            container.html(prevHTML);
            $this.find('img').attr('src', 'go.png');
            $this.removeClass('go');
        } else {
            $this.find('img').attr('src', 'stop.png')
                .end().addClass('go');
            req = $.ajax({
                url: 'go.php?go=' + $this.attr('id'),
                type: 'get',
                success: function (data) {
                    container.html(data);
                    $this.removeClass('go');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

p.s. This is a rough example to get you started. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, 
This changes the icon on the first click and calls the `go.php?go=4a`.
 
But clicking the same icon doesn't revert it back to the original icon and doesn't call `go.php?stop=4a`.

Can you help ?

Comment: I've created a DIV with name & ID of x, but no results are returned.

My go.php script is echoing the correct data.. How do i get it to x ?

Comment: If you're getting `data` in the success function, it's as easy as `container.html(data)` where `container = $('#x')`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - what you want is not possible. Changing the URL refreshes the page, so your ajax will be lost in the nick of time.

You can use anchors though (for example if you're on `go.php`, you can change the url to `go.php#go4a`, and with the proper coding, you will be able to make the page work as if the AJAX ran.

About reverting, you will need to use a flag to see its state, then do the appropriate reverts. Not sure what you need, so this is all the information I can give you.